# C function with pointers in C#

Tags: c#, c, sdl, sdl-2, cppsharp

I'm currently playing with CppSharp and I generated the bindings for the SDL2 library. It almost works, but I can't get working the event part of the library. In C, you just use the API like this

```
SDL_Event event;
while(SDL_WaitEvent(&event))
{
    if(e.type = SDL_QUIT)
        exit(0);
}
```

But in C# with the generated bindings I can't do it:

```
SDL.SDL_Event e = new SDL.SDL_Event();
while(SDL.SDL_WaitEvent(e))
{
    if(e.Type == (uint)SDL.SDL_EventType.SDL_QUIT)
        System.Environment.Exit(0);
}
```

It compiles but e.Type is always zero, which is not correct, it's like the C# object never changes internally. Is there a way to let C# pass an SDL.SDL_Event like C does.

For reference, here are the bindings (I would like to not change them, because they're generated by CppSharp):

```
[SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
[DllImport("SDL2", CallingConvention = global::System.Runtime.InteropServices.CallingConvention.Cdecl,EntryPoint="SDL_WaitEvent")]
internal static extern int SDL_WaitEvent(global::System.IntPtr @event);

public static int SDL_WaitEvent(global::SDL.SDL_Event @event)
{
    var ____arg0 = @event.__Instance;
    var __arg0 = new global::System.IntPtr(&____arg0);
    var __ret = __Internal.SDL_WaitEvent(__arg0);
    return __ret;
}
```

How can I get the event loop working in C#?

**EDIT**: SDL_Event generated struct

```
public unsafe partial struct SDL_Event
{
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size = 56)]
    public partial struct __Internal
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        internal uint type;

        [FieldOffset(0)]
        internal global::SDL.SDL_CommonEvent.__Internal common;

        [FieldOffset(0)]
        internal global::SDL.SDL_WindowEvent.__Internal window;

        [FieldOffset(0)]
        internal global::SDL.SDL_KeyboardEvent.__Internal key;

        [FieldOffset(0)]
        internal global::SDL.SDL_TextEditingEvent.__Internal edit;

        [FieldOffset(0)]
        internal global::SDL.SDL_TextInputEvent.__Internal text;

        [FieldOffset(0)]
        internal global::SDL.SDL_MouseMotionEvent.__Internal motion;

        [FieldOffset(0)]
        internal global::SDL.SDL_MouseButtonEvent.__Internal button;

        [FieldOffset(0)]
        internal global::SDL.SDL_MouseWheelEvent.__Internal wheel;

        [FieldOffset(0)]
        internal global::SDL.SDL_JoyAxisEvent.__Internal jaxis;

        [FieldOffset(0)]
        internal global::SDL.SDL_JoyBallEvent.__Internal jball;

        [FieldOffset(0)]
        internal global::SDL.SDL_JoyHatEvent.__Internal jhat;

        [FieldOffset(0)]
        internal global::SDL.SDL_JoyButtonEvent.__Internal jbutton;

        [FieldOffset(0)]
        internal global::SDL.SDL_JoyDeviceEvent.__Internal jdevice;

        [FieldOffset(0)]
        internal global::SDL.SDL_ControllerAxisEvent.__Internal caxis;

        [FieldOffset(0)]
        internal global::SDL.SDL_ControllerButtonEvent.__Internal cbutton;

        [FieldOffset(0)]
        internal global::SDL.SDL_ControllerDeviceEvent.__Internal cdevice;

        [FieldOffset(0)]
        internal global::SDL.SDL_AudioDeviceEvent.__Internal adevice;

        [FieldOffset(0)]
        internal global::SDL.SDL_QuitEvent.__Internal quit;

        [FieldOffset(0)]
        internal global::SDL.SDL_UserEvent.__Internal user;

        [FieldOffset(0)]
        internal global::SDL.SDL_SysWMEvent.__Internal syswm;

        [FieldOffset(0)]
        internal global::SDL.SDL_TouchFingerEvent.__Internal tfinger;

        [FieldOffset(0)]
        internal global::SDL.SDL_MultiGestureEvent.__Internal mgesture;

        [FieldOffset(0)]
        internal global::SDL.SDL_DollarGestureEvent.__Internal dgesture;

        [FieldOffset(0)]
        internal global::SDL.SDL_DropEvent.__Internal drop;

        [FieldOffset(0)]
        internal fixed byte padding[56];

        [SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
        [DllImport("SDL", CallingConvention = global::System.Runtime.InteropServices.CallingConvention.Cdecl,
            EntryPoint="??0SDL_Event@@QEAA@AEBT0@@Z")]
        internal static extern global::System.IntPtr cctor(global::System.IntPtr instance, global::System.IntPtr _0);
    }
```

Comment: @UnholySheep fixed, but the binding code is almost the same

Comment: Are you sure this is the exact code you are using? It shouldn't compile, since C# does not allow implicit `int` to `bool` conversion (and therefore your `while` condition should not be valid)

Comment: @UnholySheep actually there's a `== 1` in the `while` so it compiles, but I think that's not the problem. It actually returns events but they're not updated. I'm going to post the generated SDL_Event definition if that helps

Comment: Btw, there is the SDL .NET binding project on source forge https://sourceforge.net/projects/cs-sdl/ , probably all your problems already solved here